# Encrypt my external hard disk (Linux + OS X + Windows)

Tags: cross-platform, encryption, hard-disk

I have some external hard disks. I have encrypted them with the default encryption utility that comes with OS X, so I get encrypted HFS+ disks. Now I need to encrypt the same disks, but I need to be able to read them in OS X, Linux (Ubuntu distro) and Windows.

What software I could use for encrypting those external hard disks with a password? So when I go to another PC, I just have to install the software, introduce the disk, then the password and see my files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Until a yearor two back, the definitive answer would have been TrueCrypt.

I still use it myself, but, as it is no longer actively developed, you might want to choose one of the forks, based on its source code. [VeraCrypt](https://veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html) seems to be the best.

It is cross-platform, gratis and its source code is published on the web for peer review.

VeraCrpyt supports Windows / ***MacOSX*** / Linux / Source Downloads (so that, in theory, you can build it for any o/s).

Comment: Could you please confirm what OSes VeraCrypt supports? Thanks :-)

Comment: VeraCrypt supports Windows, OS X and Linux. On Linux, it is also possible to open VeraCrypt containers using [cryptsetup or zuluCrypt](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/301p17/unlocking_veracrypt_volumes_using_just_released/)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative,

Lately I've been playing with some things to store data securely on Owncloud/NextCloud.

Researching that I've found encFS as well as CryFS. Both are FUSE file systems.

The main difference is that CryFS divides everything into chunks of the same size while encFS encrypts the file.

Both encrypt the name as well.

Besides that, if you need for it to work on all platforms, I think encFS has a windows port but CryFS doesn't.

- https://www.cryfs.org
- https://vgough.github.io/encfs/